# Cannot spin instance more than 2gb memory in openstack packstack

Tags: memory, centos7, openstack, instantiation

I deployed openstack packstack (all-in-one) in centos7 server with 8vcpu and 16gb memory. Deployment of packstack openstack successful completed. I can spin instances with flavor with 2gb or less but when use 4g or 6g ith will return fail instantiate error.

```
Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance
```

This is clean openstack deployment on clean centos7 server.

when I run free -m it show below

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15845       14816         259         532         769         197
Swap:          8063        5049        3014
```

This is the 1st VM to instantiate..I puzzle and don't know where all the memory went.

From the hypervisor view

```
Type : QEMU                 
VCPUs (used): 0 
VCPUs (total): 8    
RAM (used): 0   
RAM (total): 15.5G  
Local Storage (used): 0 
Local Storage (total): 49GB 
Instances: 0
```

I have seen people with similar problem without any solution...I really need help from all you guyz...Hope someone could lead me the way.. Please do help ..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, recent versions of Packstack are rather memory-hungry. You can use [top](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) and sort by VIRT and/or RES to get an idea which components use memory most. Then try switching off parts that you don't need.

On your running server, you could try stopping the corresponding *systemd* services if you don't need them. You could also look for parameters in `/etc/<service>/<service>.conf` that configure number of workers, reduce them and restart the service. Example: `osapi_compute_workers` in one of the /etc/nova config files.

Alternatively, generate a default answer file and set appropriate parameters like CONFIG_something_INSTALL to "n". I don't know what Packstack installs by default these days; CONFIG_HEAT_INSTALL or CONFIG_CEILOMETER_INSTALL are hot candidates (of course, only if you don't need them). Then reinstall from scratch.

Comment: Hi @berndbausch noted and thanks. I have run top and seems no abnormalities of activities that load full mem utilization... just curious if got memory leak in queens... anyway I will troubleshoot further. Thanks for your good response sir.